# Question about the uniqueness of the $n^\text{th}$ cylclotomic polynomial?

Tags: definition, cyclotomic-polynomials

I am currently trying to understand the concept of a cyclotomic polynomial which, due to my absent knowledge of rings/fields/etc, is proving difficult. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), the following definition is provided:

> In mathematics, more specifically in algebra, the $n^\text{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial, for any positive integer $n$, is the unique irreducible polynomial with integer coefficients that is a divisor of $x^{n}-1$ and is not a divisor of $x^{k}-1$ for any $k < n$.

My problem with this definition is that $x^n - 1$ divides $x^n - 1$ but not $x^k - 1$ for $k < n$. Thus, since the $n^\text{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial is unique, this means that it is always $x^n - 1$?

A second definition that I have found, from [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclotomicPolynomial.html), is that the $n^\text{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial is the *irreducible* polynomial given by
$$
\Phi_n (x) = \prod_{k=1}^n \left( x - \zeta_k \right)
$$
where $\zeta_k$ denotes the 'primative $k^\text{th}$ root of unity'. However, my understanding of 'irreducible' polynomial is one which cannot be broken into smaller factors. From the definition above, $\Phi_n (x)$ can clearly be factorised, since each $\left( x - \zeta_k \right)$ represents a factor?

Comment: But $x^n -1$ isn't irreducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, and for $n=3$ the cyclotomic polynomial is $x^2+x+1=0$. That polynomial is irreducible *over $\mathbb{Q}$*, i.e. it cannot be broken into smaller factors *with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$*, which is what matters for this definition (although, as you note, it is not irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$).

In general, an easy induction argument proves that
$$x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x^2+x+1)
$$
which answers your question: $x^n-1$ is *never* irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and so the $n^{\text{th}}$ cyclotomic polynomial is *never* $x^n-1$.

One must then ponder the general question, for any $n$, whether the polynomial $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (it is for $n=3$). But that's another question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is a polynomial of the form $x^n - 1$ always divisible by $x-1$? I checked for several small values of $n$, and this seems to be the case, but I am not certain.

Comment: Sorry, this is quite clearly true - but is also irrelevant to the question, since $x^n - 1)/(x-1)$ is not necessarily irreducible.

Comment: I've added a bit more to my answer, together with an explicit answer to your question.